# What is the alternative to <c:set> after the view is built?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, facelets

what is the alternative to `<c:set>` after the view is built ?
Generally `<c:set>` works when the view is being built. After that, how do I change that ?

For example, what would be the equivalent of the following in JSF tag ? The following property is just not set after the view is built.

```
<c:set property="showPromoDetails" target="#{viewScope}" value="null" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume JSF 2.x. Put this somewhere in the view, the common convention is somewhere near the top.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{viewScope.preRenderView}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
public void preRenderView() {
    showPromoDetails = null;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. In the future questions please be more specific about the JSF impl/version used. The above is namely not available in JSF 1.x.

Comment: Sure BalusC. will do that.. You are doing a fantastic job.