# Setting a property value without taking input on JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I need to set a property value without taking input on JSF page which is as follows:

```
<ui:repeat var="i" value="#{elBean.list}" iterationStatus="loop" >
    #{i}    // I need to assign this value to a bean property
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `c:set`

```
<c:set property="i" value="SOME_VALUE"/>
```

**Also See**

- [what-is-the-alternative-to-cset-after-the-view-is-built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901232/what-is-the-alternative-to-cset-after-the-view-is-built)